# Angular ng-grid footer is not adjusting the height according to grid

Tags: ng-grid

I want to reduce the height when a row is removed from ng-grid. I am able to delete a row reduce the grid height by a row. but grid footer is not moving from its position.

here is the code I am using

--html

```
      <div class="gridStyle" ui-if="InterestInfo.length>0" ng-grid="gridOptions" ng-     style="getTableStyle()"   >

    </div>
```

--javascript

```
var varFooterTempate = '<div><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success"  ng-click="edit(row)"  > ' +
                                   ' <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>' +
                                '</button>'

$scope.getTableStyle = function () {
    var rowHeight = 35;
    var headerHeight = 30;
    var footerHeight = 30;
    return {
        height: ($scope.InterestInfo.length * rowHeight + headerHeight + footerHeight + 5) + "px"
    };
};


    $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'InterestInfo',
    headerRowHeight: 30,
    rowHeight: 35,
    footerRowHeight: 30,
    showFooter: true,
    footerTemplate: varFooterTempate,
    columnDefs: [{ field: 'name', displayName: 'Name' },
  { field: 'type', displayName: 'Type' },
  { field: 'number', displayName: 'Number' },
  { field: '', displayName: 'Action', width: 140, sortable: false, cellTemplate: editableInPopup}],
    multiSelect: false

};
$scope.removeRow = function () {


    var index = this.row.rowIndex;
    alert(index);
    $scope.gridOptions.selectItem(index, false);
    $scope.InterestInfo.splice(index, 1);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the documentation is currently wrong on this topic.  Try setting *gridFooterHeight* instead of *footerRowHeight* in your gridOptions object.

Comment: This answer got me close.  I was using `showColumnFooter: true` and had to use `columnFooterHeight: 60` in order for my grid to expand the same height I used in my css class of `div.ui-grid-footer-panel.ui-grid-footer-aggregates-row { height: 60px !important; }`  Now it looks perfect.